# Solr velocity UI - Facets query for unique value.

Tags: json, solr, velocity, facet

I do have a requirement to get unique facet counts based on a indexed field in Solr velocity UI. It seems there is a json option to get unique facet counts. Can this be used in solrconfig.xml

Here is what I tried.(From requestHandler section)

```
   <str name="facet">on</str>
   <str name="facet.missing">false</str>
   <str name="facet.field">State</str> 
   <str name="facet.query">State:&json.facet={ x : "unique(State)" }</str>
```

This throws errors.

Is there any other way to get the unique values?

thanks,

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: I had the same question when I was researching this a while ago. I couldn't find a way to add the json.facets in the solronfig.xml so that the Velocity UI will show the unique counts against the Faceted Values

Answer (score 0):

Add facet in the solr request URL &json.facet={x : "unique(manu_exact)"}

example:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json&json.facet={x : "unique(manu_exact)"}
```

change collection name accordingly, you can see facets count at the bottom.

where count: is count of all facets. x: is unique value count of facets.

Comment: I think the question is about how to set this up in the solrconfig.xml so that this will show up in the Velocity UI. I'm not sure the response here addresses that.